# How do I prevent time drift in a Debian guest on a CentOS KVM host?

Tags: debian, kvm, clock

I know I can install `ntp` in the guest, but my confused understanding of what I've Googled so far suggests this shouldn't be necessary.

The Host is CentOS 6.3 and guest is Debian Wheezy, which seems to be using the kvm clock as a time source:

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
kvm-clock
```

Is there something special I need to do to make the guest use the host clock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guest has no **direct** access to the host clock.  Instead, it uses kvm-clock which points to a memory region updated by the host, from the host's clock.  As such, the guest **is** using the host clock.  The issue is that this memory region isn't updated constantly, it's only updated when there's a VM 'event', and as such, guests can drift and then lurch back to the correct time.

The general advice, as far as I can see, is ensure the VM is doing something on a regular basis, so that it re-reads the host clock on a regular basis.

Some sources,

- https://rwmj.wordpress.com/tag/kvmclock/
- http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/KVMClock
- http://s19n.net/articles/2011/kvm_clock.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I feared. `ntpd` is sophisticated about step changes in time, so I think I'm safer installing it on the guests.

Comment: on second thoughts, I think running `hwclock --hctosys` every 10 minutes is unlikely to be any worse than `ntpd` for steps, thanks I'll do that (unless you have a better suggestion for how to make the guest re-read the host clock).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, the host writes the time to a page of memory that the guest can read. This generally means that the vm's hardware clock matches the host's, barring any bugs where the host doesn't write that page on critical events like scaling cpu speed. The issue is usually that the OS doesn't recognize that the hardware clock is changing/adjusting. A regular 'hwclock --hctosys' will update the OS per the current hardware clock, and (in my opinion) is cleaner than running an NTP daemon.

You can see this in action by running something like this in your kvm-clock guest:

```
date && hwclock --hctosys && date
Sun Jan  5 23:40:44 MST 2014
Sun Jan  5 23:40:06 MST 2014
```

Comment: For some odd reason, subsequent runs of `hwclock` take 10 or more seconds to complete. Thus the result of `date && hwclock -r && date` shows a 9 to 10 second gap. It's really not clear what the "correct" time is.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what was already said about kvm-clock, you might want to try the standard best practices - get away from tickless kernels, downshift the kernel ticks to 10 or so, enable `ntpclient`, make sure the host is not overloaded - time drift often happens during heavy CPU overcommit. If the VM has lots of virtual CPUs assigned, take that number down a few nothches too