# CentOS 6 KVM host with CentOS 6 guests kvm-clock enabled major time drift

Tags: centos, kvm, ntpd

I have a CentOS 6 KVM host with CentOS 6 guests, all 64bit. The host syncs time from NTP and has remained bang on.

All the guests have `kvm-clock` listed as `current_clocksource` but over the last 3 weeks they have drifted by about 4 hours from the host.

I was under the impression that `kvm-clock` would prevent this from happening. Even the [RHEL docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-KVM_guest_timing_management.html) seem to suggest this...

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5 and newer, and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.0 and newer, use kvm-clock as their default clock source. Running without kvm-clock requires special configuration, and is not recommended.

Normally I would always run `ntpd` in guests as well as on the host to make sure the time stays in sync.

Has anyone seen this happen before, know of any reasons this might have happened, and a way to prevent this from happening in the future?
Ideally without having `ntpd` syncing from within the guests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs also recommend running `ntpd` in guests, this is absolutely normal. `kvm-clock` syncs the guests when they boot up, but not afterwards.

Comment: Ok that's brilliant and makes sense. Don't suppose you've got a reference for that? I was thinking that it might be similar to OpenVZ where the guests are constantly synced to the host time.

Comment: hmm, not sure I can come up with the exact wording, but you can look in the code. As for using NTP in guests, that's everywhere: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-KVM_guest_timing_management.html

Comment: Fair enough, NTP it is. Found some similar things http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83934/how-do-i-prevent-time-drift-in-a-debian-guest-on-a-centos-kvm-host and here https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/kvm-pvclock/ but nothing that explicitly says it only happens on boot. Apparently when a VM 'event' occurs, whatever that is.

Comment: A VM event is a VM state change that reflects in qemu monitor. Start/Stop/Pause/etc

Comment: Ok that's perfect, makes sense now. I was expecting more of a live update thing. `ntpd` it is!

Answer (score 2):

This is the best explanation I've found for the time drift you observed:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27865

Briefly, the guest's "hardware" clock (kvm-clock) gets updated from the host's hardware clock every 5 minutes, and on "events" such as migration of a vcpu to a different physical cpu. The guest's system clock (the one you care about) will probably NOT be updated at all.

I've seen people suggest running hwclock --hctosys, but the hwclock man page says this should never be used on a running system on pain of filesystem timestamp corruption and other problems.

For now (2016-10) Red Hat recommends running ntp inside each guest as well as the host. Systems that use systemd often have systemd-timesyncd, which should be enough to keep the system clock synchronized. Systems without systemd and those running RHEL 7 (on which systemd-timesyncd is missing) can run chrony or ntp.

In the future it may no longer be necessary to run ntp in each guest. Red Hat is working on a feature request to eliminate this requirement (enhancement bug report at above link).